# Django rendering different templates in one class based view

Tags: html, django, django-class-based-views

I'm starting to use class based views for an application I'm creating but I'm nots sure how it works.

What I need is to have three different templates, and each template will show different information depending on a model field. My question is if there's a way to have only one class view that can render three different html templates with 3 different contexts, or if I need to create 3 different classes.

Using function based views, I would just do this:

```
# def humanResourcesView(request):
#     context = {
#         'data' : Document.objects.all().filter(documentType='humanResources'),
#     }
#     return render(request, 'main/hr.html', context)


# #view to display training documents after click
# def trainingView(request):
#     context = {
#         'data' : Document.objects.all().filter(documentType='training'),
#     }
#     return render(request, 'main/training.html', context)


# #view to display resource documents after click
# def reportsView(request):
#     context = {
#         'data' : Document.objects.all().filter(documentType='reports')
#     }
#     return render(request, 'main/reports.html', context)
```

But I'm not sure how it works with class based views. Currently I have this, which renders and filters data correctly for one template, but I don't know how to do multiple templates. Do I need to create 3 different classes?

```
class DocumentView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        reports = Document.objects.all().filter(documentType="reports")

        context = {
            'reports' : Document.objects.all().filter(documentType='reports')
        }
        return render(request, 'documents/reportsDocs.html', context)
```

Is there a way to only have one class, and pass a certain context depen

Comment: You can use `TemplateView` from Django generics views and override its `get_template_name` method. But in your case, you hard-coded the `documentType` so I don't think so that you can switch to different templates. To do this you need to pass your  `documentType` through url etc.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to inherit from [**`TemplateView`**](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/)
and override the `get_template_names` method to return your conditional based template.
And you would override `get_context_date` to fetch the data accordingly.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class DocumentView(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        pass

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pass
```